# Unable to search the app in the AppStore with original name

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-developer

I had published an app to AppStore and the app has been listed in the search result. But due to some reason, my app doesn't display in the search result with the original name.

For example, if my app name is **Hide&Seek** and when I just put **Hide Seek** it displays the result but not for the original name. There wasn't any issue with the app search before.

What could be the reason? Any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

How does the App Store search algorithm work is something that only Apple knows about and the App Store team doesn't make any information about it public.

So, someone from the App Store team can answer the question for you and help you with that.

You should consider contacting the right team/person within Apple. Here's some pointers for you to get started.

(I'm assuming here that your app is published on the App Store **and** you have an active membership to the Apple Developer Program.)

1. Login into your [Apple Developer Account Portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/) and click on the [Contact Us](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) link shown in the left sidebar

   [image]
2. You may consider raising a [Technical Support Incident](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/). While it's meant for seeking code level help from the engineering team, if the above approach doesn't yield a result (which I suspect won't be the case), you may try considering this approach. An active developer program membership is eligible to two technical support incidents in a single membership year, and additional two incidents can be bough for $99.
3. You may want to consider contacting [App Store Support](https://support.apple.com/apps).

I am hopeful you'd be pointed to the right team and they should be able to address your query.